# What does 'pack into' mean?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

"Yes, I suppose we'll have to get down to work soon, though I dont know how we'll able to, packed into that little space."

In the sentence above, I don't get it why it has a comma after 'able to' and why 'pack' is added with 'ed'. Please, help me know it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not packing anything. They're the ones packed into that space.

The speaker is complaining that they might not be able to do their work because they'll be packed into that little space. They need space to do the job but they won't have enough space, because they will be packed into that little space.

[ODO definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pack) of "pack":

> 2.1 (often as adjective packed) (Of a large number of people) crowd into and fill (a place):
>   *"a packed Merseyside pub"*

Let me rephrase your example:

> Yes, I suppose we'll have to get down to work soon, though I don't know how we'll be able to if we're gonna be packed into that little space.

Comment: Now It makes sense to me. Thanks a lot for your help. I didn't expect to get help so soon like this. This site is absolutely wonderful.

Comment: Just to expand a bit on Contrum's answer, this is a metaphor; it's understood that the people involved aren't actually packed in to the space, but it's evoking imagery of luggage that's packed so full there's barely any room to move, and comparing that to the space filled with people.

Comment: I concur; well expanded.